# Where can I find a "Far east"/"Japan" Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about conversion therapy in Japan (I want to know if Japan supports those or not). I searched the appropriate Stack Exchange sites, but I couldn't find any. Is there one? Perhaps a "social science" Stack Exchange site?

(If there isn't, maybe one should be created.)

Comment: Maybe you can use [travel.se]. If not that, then what are you interested in Japan more specifically.

Comment: @VLAZ I doubt Travel handles questions about [conversion therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_therapy)... Ariel, I think you might want to clarify a bit more about the type of questions you'd ask on this subject, while there isn't a site that specifically handles pseudo-science, maybe some questions can find homes on other sites.

Comment: @VLAZ as stated in the question, I want to know japan's stance on conversion therapy. I think "Politics" SE could be the fitting forum